# Passing data to the controller from a service

Tags: angularjs, service, controllers

here is my code

```
angular.module('studentList',[]);
app.service('studentData',['$http',function($http){
    return $http.get('http://purplenimbus.net/edu/students.php')
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            return err;
        });
}]);

app.controller('studentsController', ['$scope','studentData',function($scope,studentData){
    $scope.title = 'Student List';
    studentData.success(function(data){
       $scope.list = data;
    });
}]);

app.directive('students', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'student.html'
    };
});
```

I need to know how to properly pass the data from the service to the controller so it displays using the directive tag

I know the directive works and i know the service works but the controller dosent seem to be receiving the data

http://embed.plnkr.co/Pdt6GK/preview - link to my plunk

Thanks as always

Comment: We can't test demo due to the cross domain request. Are you using this on that same domain?

Comment: you have duplicated .success, so simple return $http.get('http://purplenimbus.net/edu/students.php') in service

Comment: @charlietfl , the php file is being hosted seperately from plunker

Comment: I realize that but it is a cross domain request which isn't CORS enabled and therefore fails

Comment: @ABOS i removed the success method however it still dosent show the data

Comment: @charlietfl hmm so it not possible to retrieve data from diffrent domains? perhaps if i move the php files to plunker?

Comment: No..plunker can't run php. You can take copy of json data and put that in a file on plunker and point the request at that json file

Comment: @charlietfl , that defeats the purpose of the app , i updated the code to  make it dynamic. Do i have to enable CORS on plunker or on the originating server i.e http://purplenimbus.net/edu/students.php

Comment: doesn't defeat it all...you just change the url in $http...will still make that request only it's coming from same domain and from a static json file instead. Open php url in browser...copy the data...paste into new plunker file...change url in $http request. Then save demo again

Comment: @charlietfl i see i will test it on local host. Thanks for your help. The code for the Service is correct thou right?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your service is wrong, as is it should be a `factory` instead.

Also, if you want to be able to use `studentData.success` from the controller, then you can simply return the `$http` promise from the factory:

```
app.factory('studentData', ['$http',function($http){
  return $http.get('http://purplenimbus.net/edu/students.php');
}]);
```